# Problema con traerUsuario(email:String)

Tags: angular, typescript, get

En mi servicio de backend tengo mi apartado de Usuarios donde tenga un GET para traer un usuario por el email , es unico. Lo probe en postman y anda correcto : Me tira un 302 found y me trae el json esperado.

Cuando hago la solicitud por el frontend, me tira este error :

error:

> {email: 'admin@gmail.com', id: 15, nombre: 'Admin', apellido: 'Admin',
> pass: '$2a$10$jrjKzWgmFT57ICLC6KcZeOMXh7yDEO8ovx4EiEAnowprsp59/Ubba',
> …} headers :  HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null,
> lazyInit: ƒ} message :  "Http failure response for
> http://localhost:8080/api/v1/user/traerUsuario?email=admin@gmail.com:
> 302 OK" name :  "HttpErrorResponse" ok :  false status :  302
> statusText :  "OK" url :
> "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/user/traerUsuario?email=admin@gmail.com"
> [[Prototype]] :  HttpResponseBase

CODIGO :

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
   this.email = this.tokenService.getEmail();
   this.traerUser()
  }
  

  traerUser():void{
    this.userService.traerUsuario(this.email).subscribe(NuevoUsuario =>{
      this.user = NuevoUsuario;
    })
  }
```

Este es mi servicio para traer el usuario en el backend

```
   @GetMapping("/traerUsuario")
public ResponseEntity<Optional<User>> traerUsuario(@RequestParam String email){
    Optional<User> user = service.findByEmail(email);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(user,HttpStatus.FOUND);

}
```

Comment: No es ningún error... es que has hecho que el servbicio devuelva un 302, no un 2XX. Los 2XX son OK, lo demás no

Comment: muchas gracias <3